# How to pass int[] from c# to c++ using shared memory

Tags: c#, c++, shared-memory

I'm trying to pass an array of integers from c# to c++ via a managed memory file. Text was easy enough to get working, but I'm out of my depths in the c++ environment, and am not sure how to adjust this for an array of integers.

On the c# side, I pass:

```
pView = LS.Core.Platforms.Windows.Win32.MapViewOfFile(
                hMapFile,                       // Handle of the map object
                LS.Core.Platforms.Windows.Win32.FileMapAccess.FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, // Read and write access
                0,                              // High-order DWORD of file offset 
                ViewOffset,                     // Low-order DWORD of file offset
                ViewSize                        // Byte# to map to the view
                );

byte[] bMessage2 = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(Message2 + '\0');
Marshal.Copy(bMessage2, 0, pView2, bMessage2.Length);
```

Here pView2 is the pointer to the memory mapped file.

On the c++ side, I call:

```
LPCWSTR pBuf;
pBuf = (LPCWSTR) MapViewOfFile(hMapFile, // handle to map object
           FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS,  // read/write permission
           0,
           0,
           BUF_SIZE);
```

How would I change this to handle an array of integers instead?  Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us the code for the `pView2` definition? Any reason you're not using `MemoryMappedFile`?

Comment: Why are you using memory mapped files?

Comment: @sixletter, I've added that.  I AM using memory mapped files, because it's quite fast for sharing information between applications.

Comment: @tghamm: no, your code is not using what I was referring to, [see MemoryMappedFile on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile.aspx).

Comment: Ah gotcha, yeah, I'd use that but it has .Net 4.0 as a dependence, I'd like to try and stay with 3.5 for the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) You can copy the int[] into a byte[]. You can use BitConverter.GetBytes for this or bit arithmetic (byte0 = (byte)(i >> 24); byte1 = (byte)(i >> 16); ...)

b) You can use unsafe code to bit-copy (blit) the int[] to the target byte[]

c) Maybe you can use Array.Copy. I *think* it can handle any blittable value type.

As per the comments I will elaborate on b):

```
int[] src = ...;
IntPtr target = ...;
var bytesToCopy = ...;

fixed(int* intPtr = src) {
 var srcPtr = (byte*)intPtr;
 var targetPtr = (byte*)target;
 for(int i from 0 to bytesToCopy) {
  targetPtr[i] = srcPtr[i];
 }
}
```

Comment: Admittedly I'm still a bit lost here.  For the moment I've resigned myself to parsing a string instead.

Comment: You copy your string into the byte[] bMessage2. You can also copy your int[] into a byte[] so you can use it with memory mappings.

Comment: thanks, I think I see the path to get that to work, but here's my sub-question.  What kind of performance gain (if any) will I realistically see going from reading ~5k ints in a string and casting them while adding to a vector, or using some bitwise math to generate them from a byte as would be suggested by your solution?

Comment: Your string version will be extremely inefficient. You will be converting numbers to strings and back a _lot_. YOu will generate a lot of garbage. Version b) is the fastest and easiest. Just get a pointer to the int[] and copy the ints directly into the memory-mapped area in a single for loop.

Comment: Ok, I'm like 90% there conceptually, sorry I'm a bit out of my depths here. For method b: I think I know how to get a pointer to the int[], but I'm not sure how to actually copy them over as you've described.  Presumably  `int[] tArray = null;
                unsafe
                {
                    fixed (int* pArray = tArray)
                    {
                        IntPtr intPtr = new IntPtr((void*)pArray);
                    }
                }` gets me my pointer to an int.  How do I blit it from there?

Comment: I added the necessary pseudo-code. The trick is to first reduce the problem to copy from one byte* to another byte* a fixed amount of bytes. That by itself is pretty simple.

Comment: For added performance, import the memcpy function using PInvoke. It will be a lot faster than this primitive loop. You can also use Reflector to look inside of the System.Buffer.memcpy method.

Comment: Perfect, that worked flawlessly @usr, just mapped them as (int *) on the c++ and now I'm good to go as soon as I wrap a semaphore around both sides.